# exporting non_public type through public API

Tags: java, netbeans

I have written this code in Netbeans but it will show this warning for the name of this method ,would you please help me for what it shows this warning? thanks

```
  public Node returnNode(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {

    if (index < 0 || index > size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            pointer = pointer.getNext();
        }
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

Comment: Is "pointer" a member of your class?

Answer (score 4):

The non-public type is your `Node` class in this case. Most likely you just want to declare it as `public class Node` instead of just `class Node`.

Netbeans seems to be quite focused on large projects. In a scenario where you are writing a library package that will be used by external code, this warning makes a lot of sense. If you are writing a small standalone app, there is little harm in setting the visibility of all your classes to `public`.

Answer (score 0):

That warning is understandable.  A public method that returns a non-public type is going to be hard to use.  For a start, unless the return type is *visible* to the caller, it won't be able to assign it to anything.

You should probably change the visibility of either the method or the return type.

Answer (score 0):

Your **public** method returns a Node, from the error I would guess that the Node class is not declared **public** and can't be seen by the same classes as your method.
So instead of

```
 public Node returnNode(int index)
```

those classes will only see

```
 public Object returnNode(int index)
```

To remove the warning make the **Node** class **public**.